# Is there currently any way to vote on what music you play?

Tags: itunes, software-recommendation, appletv

iTunes used to have a "party shuffle"/"iTunes DJ" feature that allowed users to vote on what was played, but as far as I know it was yanked a long time ago and nothing else replaced it.  Is there currently any way to do the same sort of thing?  (By "currently" I mean using current software, whether from Apple or a third party, not by digging up ancient software.)

It would be fine if involves connecting to iTunes from other computers or from iOS devices, or whether it involves an Apple TV as the central point of control, where devices or computers connect to the Apple TV.

All I want is some way to allow input from multiple people in an office to determine what gets played and what gets skipped.  (It doesn't even need to be, strictly speaking, a "voting" metaphor that is used.  It could be  that anyone can veto specific songs, or the most popular go first, or whatever.)

Comment: [This Meta answer](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/a/2181/88313) provides a good guide to follow when asking for recommendations. There's also an [entire SE site](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) dedicated to software & hardware recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If voting is not relevant, and money is not an issue, you can set up a [Spotify Collaborative Playlist](https://support.spotify.com/us/using_spotify/playlists/create-playlists-with-your-friends/).
It allows you to invite any Spotify user to edit your playlist.

Other than that, searching for "[playlist voting app](https://www.google.cl/search?q=playlist+voting+app&rlz=1CDGOYI_enCL711CL711&oq=playlist+voting&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l3.15974j0j4&hl=en-US&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8)" returns a great amount of apps that do different versions of what you are looking for, but I haven't tried any of them.

https://outloud.dj/ seems particularly promising:

> At your next party, everybody controls the music.
>   Mash your Spotify and iTunes playlists with those of your friends and build the ultimate playlist.
>   Add any song through Spotify, even if you don't have an account.
>   Project your playlist onto your TV with the push of a button.
>   The app is free and no sign-ins and set-ups required.

Comment: after a really quick review of the results, outloud.dj appears to be the only one that supports both iTunes and Spotify. Perfect for us.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Apple Music to create a channel for yourself and others who can dj and queue up songs together on the same platform channel. They would just need to know your channel name and have iTunes/Apple Music etc. a matching platform.